# Issue with .count() method c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem while using `.count()` method on CloudTableQuery

```
    public void AccessEntites()
    {
        CloudTableQuery entries =
            (from e in ServiceContext.CreateQuery<T>(TableName)
             select e).AsTableServiceQuery();

        int count = entries.Count(); //An error occurred while processing this request.
    }
```

I just want to count the total number of elements we have in entries. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Give the full exception details.  The count is not the problem, the query is.  It only executes when you try to access the results (with .count())

Comment: What is the exception/error details, what does AsTableServiceQuery do?  Is that TableServiceExtensionMethods.AsTableServiceQuery? ...

Comment: Is there any reason your query expression can't be `CloudTableQuery entries = ServiceContext.CreateQuery<T>(TableName).AsTableServiceQuery();`?

Comment: Yes , the reason is that i did`nt know about this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your entries is not null.

```
int count;
if (entries != null)
  count = entries.Count();
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this answer is accepted, as it is clearly not the correct one. When 'entries' would be null, the result would be a NullReferenceException, and not "An error occured while processing this request".

Comment: @user1527329 I haven't done much with Azure, so you might be right, but the OP never did give us the actual error message.  I could be wrong, but it looks like [CloudTableQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758648) implements IEnumerable, so Count should be available.

Comment: Sorry, but I think that's very naive. "An error occurred while processing this request." is a very common error message in .NET, so it's safe to assume this is the (most top) error message he got, and not the NullReferenceException that you'd get with a null reference.

Answer (score 1):

This code does not work, because the Azure Table Storage (Cloud Table) does not support a Count() operation to get the amount of entities. The only way to get this value is to retrieve all entities (better a small projection) and count the retrieved entities.

edit:
Here's a link to the Microsoft social forum where this was also said in april 2012 (still valid).

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-BE/windowsazuredata/thread/440e19fe-f3e0-4c98-a28f-85c535f3d735

Comment: The result type is an IEnumerable, or not?

Comment: It is IQueryable. But neverless the Azure Table Storage really does not provide many functionalities that you'd expect, having an IQueryable.

Comment: Having read the (beta looking) help, I believe that is right. +1

Comment: Pretty sad when absolutely correct answers get voted down, and obvious wrong answers get accepted.

Comment: I don't think he really cared at all what answer he accepted.